# Halting problem with extra input

Tags: computability, halting-problem

Can there be a function `HALT(f, y)` so that:

- There are some `x` such that `f(x)` halts iff there are some `y` such that `HALT(f, y)` return true;
- There are some `x` such that `f(x)` doesn't halt iff there are some `y` such that `HALT(f, y)` return false;
- `HALT` always halt and return a boolean

? It makes lots of old conflict don't work. E.g. If `f(x)` loops forever when `HALT(f, x)` is true, `HALT` may return true for half of `x`.

Comment: What are the inputs? What do you mean by writing `f(x)` as an input?

Comment: @xskxzr Take a function with an input as input 1

Comment: Do you mean `HALT(f, x, y)`?

Comment: @xskxzr No. `HALT` only takes two arguments

Comment: I still don't get your point. You said "can there be a function `HALT(f(x), y)`...", but `HALT(f(x), y)` is an **expression**, not a **function**. So what is your function?

Comment: @xskxzr Maybe `bool HALT(void(*f)(int x), int y)` you want?

Comment: You should fix your notation. What is the difference between `HALT(f(x),y)` and `HALT(f,y)`? You should make sure you understand the difference between `f(x)` and `f`. And also, your question is unclear. For instance, you cannot say "`HALT` returns true on some `y`". You should presumably say something like "there exists `y` such that `HALT(f,y)` returns true".

Comment: @AndrejBauer Unclarified

Comment: Is `HALT` supposed to be computable? Is `f` supposed to be partial computable?

Comment: @AndrejBauer `f` have access to `HALT`. It's fine whether `HALT` is computable (but it's good if whether computable is shown)

Comment: Do you mean `HALT` and `f` are Turing machines rather than functions? It is meaningless to say a function halts.

Comment: @xskxzr Maybe, if you treat "function" as "box that take input and provide output"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean "Turing machine" by "function", otherwise it is meaningless to say a function halts on some input.

Suppose $\mathrm{HALT}$ exists, then we construct a Turing machine $H$ as follows:

On input $\langle M, w\rangle$ where $M$ is an (encoding of) Turing machine:

1. Construct a Turing machine $N_{\langle M, w\rangle}$ with input $x$ as follows: run $M$ on $x$ and return what $M$ returns.
2. Run $\mathrm{HALT}$ on $\langle N_{\langle M, w\rangle}, 0\rangle$ and return what $\mathrm{HALT}$ returns.

Note the result of running $N_{\langle M, w\rangle}$ has nothing to do with its input $x$. If $M$ halts on $w$, $N_{\langle M, w\rangle}$ halts on all inputs, thus $\mathrm{HALT}( N_{\langle M, w\rangle}, 0)$ returns true. otherwise $N_{\langle M, w\rangle}$ halts on no input, thus $\mathrm{HALT}( N_{\langle M, w\rangle}, 0)$ returns false.

Now we can see $M$ halts on $w$ if and only if $H$ accepts $\langle M, w\rangle$. Since $H$ always halts, $H$ is a decider for the normal halting problem, a contradiction!

So $\mathrm{HALT}$ does not exist.